# Open Source Web Form Builder With Save to Spreadsheet or Database

Tags: application, html, data

Does anyone know of any open source tools that do essentially what Google Forms does.  My company decided I could not use google forms because they did not want their info in the cloud, but for the task at hand it would have been perfect.  Now I need to find a way to create some web forms and store the replies in a centralized, searchable location.  I was hoping their was already some open source software out there I could install on Cent 7 to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all web apps can be described as a database-backed form. For a no-coding approach, I'd recommend Drupal with the Webform module. WordPress with Gravityform is also an option.